# Creating a 2-D array whose first elements come from a 1-D array

Tags: java, array

I am trying to full one dimensional array in two dimensional array in Java.I did it using this way, is there another way better than this? .

```
public double[][] getResult(double[] data, int rowSize) {
int columnSize = data.length;
double[][] result = new double[columnSize][rowSize];
for (int i = 0; i < columnSize; i++) {
    result[i][0] = data[i];
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: I think what you are doing is pretty much the best way honestly, I suppose you may be able to use Array.copyOf or system.arrayCopy or whatever the array copy commands are for Java but this is clean since you are translating from 1d to 2d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part, what you are doing is fine (like @Ashwin commented on your question).

About the only thing I really don't like is the name of the function `getResult`. That name is just really useless. How about `convert2D` or something? Your other variable names are well put together, and make sense.

Another issue you may run in to is if someone specifies bad input values. Your code will fail with a `NoSuchElementException` if someone sets a `rowSize` of `0`.

From a performance perspective, I expect that your code is pretty much as fast as it can be too - in a single-threaded process.

Using a Java 8 stream you can possibly make the process a bit more parallel, but it would be more complicated to read. Still, I thought it would be an interesting thing to see..... though, in a production system, I would be happy to see your code instead (i.e. the following code is just a thought, not a recommendation):

```
public static double[][] convert2D(double[] data, int rowSize) {
    return IntStream.range(0, data.length)
        .parallel()
        .mapToObj(i -> {
            double[] row = new double[rowSize];
            row[0] = data[i];
            return row;
        })
        .toArray(s -> new double[s][]);
}
```

The above has the advantage that each row may be created in a different thread, and "all CPUs" on your system will be creating rows. I did some performance benchmarks, and, if the rowSize is small (10 or so) then your code is faster. If the row size starts getting larger (like 1000 or so) then the parallel code starts getting faster.

Even though the stream code can sometimes be faster, I would still probably prefer to use your code.

If you want raw numbers (Note the unit for the 10-size row is MicroSeconds, and for 1000 size row is MilliSeconds), this is the timing for row-size of 10 for 1000 rows, run 1000 times:

```
Task 1d2d -> Single: (Unit: MICROSECONDS)
  Count    :      1000      Average  :   62.9370
  Fastest  :   41.4460      Slowest  : 1383.5230
  95Pctile :   95.9190      99Pctile :  124.3400
  TimeBlock : 91.553 72.914 55.230 65.829 66.551 48.998 60.405 49.428 63.745 54.717
  Histogram :   887   109     3     0     0     1

Task 1d2d -> Stream: (Unit: MICROSECONDS)
  Count    :       1000      Average  :   145.3900
  Fastest  :    20.9210      Slowest  : 85596.0480
  95Pctile :   115.2600      99Pctile :   317.3620
  TimeBlock : 983.900 101.962 61.807 49.069 57.070 36.698 32.841 34.045 45.761 50.754
  Histogram :   519   339   116    17     4     0     4     0     0     0     0     1
```

This is the timing for row-size 1000 for 1000 rows run 1000 times:

```
Task 1d2d -> Single: (Unit: MILLISECONDS)
  Count    :     1000      Average  :   1.3570
  Fastest  :   1.1601      Slowest  :   7.7698
  95Pctile :   2.5799      99Pctile :   4.2958
  TimeBlock : 2.175 1.387 1.284 1.225 1.217 1.244 1.253 1.314 1.260 1.211
  Histogram :   948    44     8

Task 1d2d -> Stream: (Unit: MILLISECONDS)
  Count    :     1000      Average  :   0.9919
  Fastest  :   0.5680      Slowest  :  92.7422
  95Pctile :   2.2405      99Pctile :   4.0231
  TimeBlock : 2.672 1.074 0.742 0.811 0.763 0.773 0.762 0.733 0.772 0.817
  Histogram :   932    19    45     3     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: thank you :) . please, what did you use for performance benchmarks ?

Comment: @EslamAli - a few of us here on Code Review contributed to https://github.com/rolfl/MicroBench - it runs, benchmarks, and reports performance metrics. It also has a feature for "fitting" a time-complexity curve on to a function for different input sizes.

Comment: thank you , it's great work ! .but i'm wondering how is the single work faster for row-size 1000 than for row-size of 10 ?